# Is it possible to extend services dynamically in a dependency injection?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, dependencies, extending

I am working on a Symfony2 project. Symfony has a very cool dependency injection system, but I am wondering if it's possible to dynamically extend some services...

For instance, I have a vendor service X, registered by a third party library/bundle. Now, I need to extend that service, let's call that one Y...
I can do that by using the same service ID in the services configuration. So that's all good...

But now, I need a service Z that extends from Y, without the service knowing it's actually extending from Y instead of X (since the vendor service is X), so I can use service Z as if it were X in all descending application logic without losing the functionality of Y.

I hope my explaination makes a little bit of sense, basically my question is: is this possible? And if so, how should I go about achieving this?

Comment: You can decorate an existing service instead of replacing is: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services

Comment: This seems to be doing what I need... It's completely new to me so I'm going to research this solution, thanks! Maybe if you add this as an answer and it turns out to be the best solution, I'll mark it as most helpful so other people having this problem will see it.

Comment: I added an answer. Feel free to ask if you need further information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate an existing service instead of replacing it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services (in case more than one definition is decorating an existing one, you can also control the order in which the decoration is applied).

Comment: Sticking with this answer in combination with using container parameters as placeholders for classnames.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how tied is your Z, Y and X, but the way to achieve that is using compiler pass, it will allow you to change a definition and the class of a determined service, a simple integration with a bundle would look like:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html

The complete documentation on how the container compile is:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html

Its not going to be trivial since you have to understand how your bundles are talking to each other! But I hope its enough.

Comment: I know how compiler passes / bundles work (I realize my question isn't 100% clear) but will this work in a situation where service Z is not aware of the fact it's actually extending Y instead of X?

You could think of it as a 'layered' definition structure where a service with the ID of X always uses the deepest structure of extending no matter how deep down we extend it...

Comment: I think its possible, of course you will have to make sure about which calls you are going to replace, it can also be a bit dangerous in case the bundles get some updates. Have you check if you have another way to do it with the bundle? Like events

Comment: I would use this mostly for adding new methods to existing services. But maybe something as simple as setting the class name of the service as a container parameter would work... Thanks for your input. You got my upvote, but leaving the question open so other people can leave their opinion. Will mark one as the most efficient solution in the end :)

Comment: No problem, its seems a pretty specific question about your set up, I hope someone else can help you better :)